# php number format with several rules

Tags: php, numbers, format

given a number and n, I want to format it in the following way:

1. if it's an integer(without any decimal point), just return it
2. if it has x decimal point, only show m decimal point where m is the minimum of x and n.

`number_format` can't do this, what would be the easiest way to achieve this?
 
a few examples:

```
input: number = 60, n=1, output: 60
input: number=60.0, n=0, output: 60
input: number = 60.0623, n=1, output: 60.0
input: number = 60.06, n=3, output: 60.06
```

Comment: I don't understand point 2 at all. Can you provide sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: I still don't understand the question

Comment: Where does the `n` come from?

Comment: n is an input to the program

Comment: So do you want `number_format` style formatting, or not? (thousands separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is

```
round($number,$maxdecimals)
```

Comment: This does not add thousand separators.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$number = 12345;
$maxdecimals = 5;
echo rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number,$maxdecimals),"0"),".");
```

This will trim off trailing zeroes, and the decimal point if there are only zeroes following it. In this case, you'll get `12,345`.

Comment: Good solution.  It leaves out a couple edge cases, but likely nothing the OP cares about.

Comment: Try with `$number = 1000`.  Doh.

Comment: Might work better with a regex (but be careful of what the thousand separator character is).

Comment: @therefromhere As long as `$maxdecimals` is non-zero, it's fine because `number_format` will return `1,000.00000`

Comment: @Kolink Have you tested that? ;)  hint: rtrim will remove both `0` and `.`, so `$number = 1000` becomes `rtrim(1,000.000, ".0")` = `1,`